# Using multiple page objects in one Geb test

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I'm trying to write a basic log in geb test using spock. I have created 2 page objects, one for the login page, and another for the page you are taken to after login.

Login page

```
package Pages

import geb.Page

class loginPage extends Page {
    static url = 'login/'
    static at = {title == "Login to TalentBank"}
    static content = {
        logo {$(".center-img img")}
        emailHeader {$(".form-group label", text:"Email")}
        emailTextBox {$('#email')}
        pwdHeader {$(".form-group label", text:"Password")}
        pwdTextBox {$("#password")}
        loginButton {$("#loginButton")}
    }
}
```

Home page

```
package Pages

import geb.Page

class homePage extends Page {
    static at = {title == "Home"}
    static content = {
        tile1 {$("#page-container > div.container-fluid > div > div:nth-child(2) > div")}
    }
}
```

TestSpec. This is a basic test to go to the login page, enter user credentials, click the login button, wait for an element on the home page, then verify you are on the home page.

```
import Pages.loginPage
import Pages.homePage
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec


class loginPageSpec extends GebReportingSpec {


    def "Log in to TalentBank Core"(){
        given:
        to loginPage
        waitFor {loginButton.isDisplayed()}

        when:
        emailTextBox.value("Ruxin")
        pwdTextBox.value("Test1234")
        loginButton.click()

        then:
        waitFor {tile1.isDisplayed()}
        at homePage
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the below error

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Unable to resolve
>   tile1 as content for Pages.loginPage, or as a property on its
>   Navigator context. Is tile1 a class you forgot to import?

Its looking for tile1 in loginPage instead of homePage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `at` in location in the test, I would also add page reference, you'll benefit from the autocomplete.

Login page

```
package Pages

import geb.Page

class LoginPage extends Page {

    static url = 'login/'

    static at = {
           title == "Login to TalentBank"
    }

    static content = {
        logo         {$(".center-img img")}
        emailHeader  {$(".form-group label", text:"Email")}
        emailTextBox {$('#email')}
        pwdHeader    {$(".form-group label", text:"Password")}
        pwdTextBox   {$("#password")}
        loginButton  {$("#loginButton")}
    }
}
```

Home page

```
package Pages

import geb.Page

class HomePage extends Page {

    static at = {
           waitFor {title == "Home"} // Add waitFor here to verify on page
    }

    static content = {
        tile1 {$("#page-container > div.container-fluid > div > div:nth-child(2) > div")}
    }
}
```

TestSpec:

```
import Pages.LoginPage
import Pages.HomePage
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec


class LoginPageSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "Log in to TalentBank Core"(){
        given:
        Page loginPage = to LoginPage
        waitFor {loginPage.loginButton.isDisplayed()}

        when:
        loginPage.emailTextBox.value("Ruxin")
        loginPage.pwdTextBox.value("Test1234")

        and: "Click login"
        loginPage.loginButton.click()

        then: "Check at home page"
        Page homePage = at HomePage

        and:
        waitFor {homePage.tile1.isDisplayed()}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to get this test to work with your suggestion. I am seeing the test fails immediately on the then: step. It tries to verify it is on homePage, before waiting for that page to load. I need it to wait before verifying I am at the homePage. I tried moving the "waitFor {homePage.tile1.isDisplayed()}" above the then: at Homepage step, but that doesn't work with an error of "No such property: tile1 for class: Pages.homePage"

Comment: Are you getting the right title ("Home")? If does it work if you try a different element, preferably one with ID?

Comment: The right title is Home. However, the test was trying to verify the title was equal to "Home" before the actual page loaded. So it was failing because the title still equaled "Login" from the previous page.I made a slight change to my homePage page object, and it appears to have solved my issue. Instead of "static at = {title == "Home"}, I changed it to "static at = {waitFor {title == "Home"}}"

Answer (score 0):

Modify LoginPage page object with

```
loginButton(to: HomePage)  {$("#loginButton")}
```

this will switch scope to HomePage page object and tile1 is present there

basic usage, no error + redirect :

```
loginButton.click()
```

in case #loginButton triggered an error, no redirect, then overload loginButton call like this:

advanced usage, error + no redirect :

```
loginButton(LoginPage).click()
```